mobile device cannot take photo ->The camera device has encountered a serious error
it.takePicture(
outputFileOptions,
imgCaptureExecutor,
object : ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback {
override fun onImageSaved(outputFileResults: ImageCapture.OutputFileResults) {
Log.d("vishal","onImageSavedCallback");
Log.i(TAG, "The image has been saved in ${file.toUri()}")
                }

....
when I am trying to take photo in my device IQOO Z6 android 14 so I am getting this error
CameraCaptureSession    com.jio.jiothings                    E  Session 0: Exception while stopping repeating:
android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException: CAMERA_ERROR (3): The camera device has encountered a serious error
at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.checkIfCameraClosedOrInError(CameraDeviceImpl.java:2559)
at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.stopRepeating(CameraDeviceImpl.java:1383)
at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraCaptureSessionImpl.close(CameraCaptureSessionImpl.java:598)
at androidx.camera.camera2.internal.SynchronizedCaptureSessionBaseImpl.close(SynchronizedCaptureSessionBaseImpl.java:476)
at androidx.camera.camera2.internal.CaptureSession.release(CaptureSession.java:489)
at androidx.camera.camera2.internal.Camera2CameraImpl.releaseSession(Camera2CameraImpl.java:528)
at androidx.camera.camera2.internal.Camera2CameraImpl.resetCaptureSession(Camera2CameraImpl.java:1243)
at androidx.camera.camera2.internal.Camera2CameraImpl.closeCamera(Camera2CameraImpl.java:442)
at androidx.camera.camera2.internal.Camera2CameraImpl$StateCallback.handleErrorOnOpen(Camera2CameraImpl.java:1690)
at androidx.camera.camera2.internal.Camera2CameraImpl$StateCallback.onError(Camera2CameraImpl.java:1647)
at androidx.camera.camera2.internal.CameraDeviceStateCallbacks$ComboDeviceStateCallback.onError(CameraDeviceStateCallbacks.java:121)
at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl$14.run(CameraDeviceImpl.java:2591)
